# How to differentiate between a missed call and an refuse to answer?

Tags: android, dialing

I am designing an application in which I need to differentiate between a call rejected by the receiver (by pressing the dialing button) with the one not answered and is disconnected by the one who is dialing. is there anything that makes a differentiation since both of these come under the missed call category in Android?

Comment: Yes i have the same question.If anyone has this answer, please help us. I have tried it , but i couldn't differentiate these two.

Answer (score 2):

You are lacking some details; please advise.

Are you referring to the Call Log provider `android.provider.CallLog.Calls`?  There are only 3 call types defined.  Can you provide the data of all the fields for such a Call Log entry?

The only other way (we know of) to tell is to watch the Phone State (via `IntentReceiver`) and track the transitions yourself.  Most likely, a transition of Ringing to Idle would indicate the call was refused instead of answered, in which case it would transition Ringing to Offhook.